# Another if in if and another id in else (doesn't read the else at all) - bash

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

When I run this peace of code, which check some conditions on the fields of sent.txt and recieved.txt in the folder of each worker and prints his name, if the conditions are true:

```
function to_print_suspicious {
 while read name; do
files=("sent.txt received.txt")
for file in $files;do
    if ((`cat "$name/$file"|cut -f1`==0)) && ((`cat "$name/$file"|cut -f5|grep -c -w $1`>0 )) || ((`cat "$name/$file"|cut -f4|grep -c -w $1` > 0)) ; then
        echo $name
    fi
done 
done | uniq
}

ls | to_print_suspicious $1
```

I get a long list of error:

```
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: scott@gmail.com
 dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0")
amanda
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
1==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: scott@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@fancystudios.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@fancystudios.com==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
1==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: dan@animation.com
scott@gmail.com
erin@gmail.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@animation.com
scott@gmail.com
erin@gmail.com==0")
jennifer
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
1==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: scott@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0")
melissa
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
1==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: scott@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@gmail.com
dan@animation.com
erin@gmail.com==0")
michael
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
1==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: dan@fancystudios.com
scott@gmail.com
kelly@beststudios.com
erin@animation.com==0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@fancystudios.com
scott@gmail.com
kelly@beststudios.com
erin@animation.com==0")
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc3: line 6: ((: 0
0==0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0==0")
```

I think the problem is the use of && and || operators here, how can I fix this ?

**In Addition, the format of sent.txt and recieved.txt:**
sent:

```
scott@gmail.com 2015-11-30  23:14   Thanks for the awesome present!
dan@animation.com   2015-11-29  22:15   Some cool reviews
erin@gmail.com  2015-11-29  09:35   Vacation this summer
```

recieved:

```
0   kevin@animation.com 2015-11-30  09:14   Notes from the meeting
1   shannon@animation.com   2015-11-29  08:21   Some new ideas for movies
```

Comment: Posting the script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ reveals some problems. Also, provide a sample file so we can test locally. To me, the way you are doing comparisons seems a bit weird. What is the overall idea of it?

Comment: sent.txt and recieved.txt are a little bit different. I'll add an example. But the idea is if it is recieved.txt: print the name of the worker if and only if the first field (column) is 0 and the parameter ($1) shows at least 1 time in the fifth column or if it is sent.txt, the print worker's name if and only if the parameter shows at least one time at the fourth column.

Comment: interesting problem, but you should really consider using `awk` to have all of this run in one process (maybe), and have much clearer set of code. see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html for a good intro. Good luck.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious: you `cut` the first field of the "sent" file, and that value is not a number. You clearly need different logic to handle the two different files.

Comment: glenn jackman, you're right, first I divided it to 2 different cases, but then I wanted to make one condition and make it shorter. So it couldn't be united for one check in your opinion ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
function to_print_suspicious {
while read name; do
files=("sent.txt received.txt")
    for file in $files;do
        if [[ $file=="recieved.txt" ]]; then
            if((`cat "$name/$file"|cut -f5|grep -c -w $1`>0)) && [[ `cat "$name/$file"|cut -f1`=0 ]]; then
            echo $name
            fi
        else
            if (( `cat "$name/$file"|cut -f4|grep -c -w $1` > 0 )); then
            echo $name
            fi
        fi
    done 
done | uniq
}
ls | to_print_suspicious $1
```

Why here only the first if works and the else doesn't (if I write instead else another full if wih condition it works) ?